# Getting The XML Text Of A .xib File

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, nsstring, xib

I know .xib files are really .xml files (as evidenced primarily by the fact that I can rename their extension and open them in text edit and dashcode), so theoretically, it would be possible to open a xib as xml and parse it in an application.  I took a look in the Build Settings for my sample app, and found that xib's aren't compiled, rather they are Copy bundle Resources.  Sounds good, right?  But the files are giving me (null) strings when I try and get their text with these methods:

```
 NSString *string = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Empty" ofType:@"xib"];
    NSString *xmlString = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:string encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] retain];
    NSLog(@"%@", xmlString);
    [textView setText:xmlString];
```

It NSLog's (null) both for `xmlString` and for `string`.  So I thought of trying it with another Copy Bundle Resource, so I changed `string` to this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"InfoPlist" ofType:@"strings"];
```

and it logged a perfect file path!  However, xmlString still logged (null).

Then, I tried getting an error code, and I got this:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 258.)
```

It makes me think there is some extra compiling going on behind the scenes with .xib files (I read somewhere that they are turned into nibs by the compiler) that is making them unreadable or unreachable.  But there are apps out that I know of ([Interface](http://lesscode.co.nz/interface?ref=devsdk) being a prime example) that can read and write .xib files.

So, can anyone help me get the xml of a .xib file?

Comment: Are you sure Interface reads and/or exports xib files?

Comment: It's a touted feature on their site.

Comment: Well, I shouldn't really have asked that question :) Even if they do, they manipulate xib files which are xml.

Comment: You know what, I just realized there is no xib import feature!  They are manipulating pure XML, then containing it in a .xib file format.  Thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually xib files are compiled into nib files. Use Show Package Contents on the compiled .app and you will see that there are no xib files but nib files instead.

**Edit** It looks like the nib file format is a proprietary format. But I am not sure.

Form Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/NotesForLocalizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000044-DontLinkElementID_1):

> The original format uses files with extension .nib. This a proprietary, binary format for the representation of Interface Builder user interface objects and connections.

**Edit 2** It looks like there is some [option](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1) to prevent Xcode from compiling the xib files into nib files. But I am still not sure about how to do that, and what is the actual result.

**Edit 3** I tried that on Xcode. When I turned Flatten Complied Xib files to No, I still got nib files in the binary but they are not compressed this time. Inside these nib files there is a file designtime.nib that has an xml format.

Comment: OK, got cocoa error 261 from that one.  What encoding are nibs in?

Comment: @CodaFi - You can compile the app and keep the nib files in xml format: see my edited answer.